# Error:rendered manifests contain a resource already contain?

Tags: devops

Error:rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists.unable to continue with install:could not get information about the resource:secret "gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner"is forbidden:user"system:node:staging.online"cannot get resource "secrets"in api group in the namespace default no relationship between node staging.online and this objects

Comment: Can you add more details on what you are trying to do? What did you try? Your question is unclear and not reproduceable.

Comment: while doing it i got the error as ``` Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the resource: secrets "gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner" is forbidden: User "system:node:staging.online" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default": no relationship found between node "staging.online" and this object ```

Comment: While doing what?